# What is the distinction between interacting picture and non-interacting picture

Tags: solid-state-physics

How would you make a distinction between interacting picture, and
non-interacting picture.

I think that in solid state physics, when we ignore the interaction
between electrons on sites far away from each other (e.g., in the
tight-binding model), then we are proceeding in non-interacting
picture. On the contrary, when we consider interactions between more
particles, the physics becomes the hard many-body problems in
interacting picture.

I was asked this problem by my professor and he was not satisfied by
this.

Now I thought, could I characterize non-interacting picture, as
containing all physics starting from the following Hamiltonian:

$$
    \hat{H} = \sum_{A,B} \psi^\dagger_A H_{AB} \psi_B
$$

where $A,B$ labels lattice sites and spins, and $\psi^\dagger,\psi$
are fermion creation and annihilation operators. $H_{AB}$ is the
$1$st-quantized Hamiltonian, essentially a matrix.

Comment: Is it possible your professor was asking you about the Dirac interaction picture? As in intermediate mixture of the Schroedinger and Heisenberg picture. Otherwise the term picture is a bit confusing, one usually refers to (non-)interacting systems and not pictures because interactions fundamentally change the physics.

Comment: @Stephan Err, no. I just provide the professors problem as a background that could be safely ignored. But your point of "interaction fundamentally change the physics" could be used to distinguish non-interaction and interaction systems right? How would you describe the "fundamentally" change brought by the interaction?

Comment: There are many examples of interesting solid-state applications that involve interaction effects, take for example BCS superconductivity. Maybe you could clarify what your actual question is?

Comment: @Stephan Ah! I think I am faced the exact reason why it is so hard to quantify the distinction between them. Maybe I should close this question as it is hard to find formulate my question. Thanks for you talk!